# How to access a TextView element in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, layout, widget

I am testing a simple widget in android and using Alarms to update a TextView at regular intervals. The problem is that in the BroadcastReceiver class I cannot access the TextView element, which I want to get updated when the alarm expires. The class is being called properly because the Toast i have put there is giving the appropriate message. The following code is from the class where I configure the widget and set the timers.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
     super.onCreate(bundle);

     Intent intent = getIntent();
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     if(extras != null){
      mWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(WidgetConfigure.this);
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(WidgetConfigure.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
      views.setTextViewText(R.id.quote, "Widget Loaded From Activity");
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mWidgetId, views);

      setTimer(); //set the timers...
      setResult();// set the result...
     }
 }
```

Now i want to update the same TextView when the BroadCastReceiver is called after the timer expires. I have tried the code provided in the ExampleAppWidget example provided in android api demos and that isnt working out. How can i set the required text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot directly change something in an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver. Because when a broadcast receiver get called, the activity maybe not exist. YOu can send messages to an activity (if the activity exists), or if the activity does not exist you can start it and put some flags in Intent

update:
Here is an ugly way:

```
class YourActivity extends xxxx {
   private static YourActivity mInst;

   public static YOurActivity instance() {
             return mInst;
   }

   /// Do your task here.
   public void setViewText(xxxx) ;

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
     ...
     mInst = this;
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
     ...
     mInst = null;
   }
}
```

And in your BroadcastReceiver:

```
   YOurActivity inst = YOurActivity.instance();
   if(inst != null)  { // your activity can be seen, and you can update it's context 
       inst.setViewText...
   }
```

Comment: I want to call the same activity which is mentioned above(which also sets the alarm) but a different method in it to set another text in the TextView element. SO I need to know how I can call this activity from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: chek out my update. Again, an activity and a broadcast receiver is independent. When your receiver got called, the activity may not exist. Even the broadcast is created in the activity.

Comment: just came across this.   I tried your sample code Kevin, but even with the activity sitting on the screen, the alarm receiver would return a null when trying to call "setViewText..."     I ended up going with a broadcast receiver and passing an action back from the alarmreceiver.

Comment: @kevin lynx - Thanks for the ugly way bro!                                        I'm interested to know the proper way of doing this.                   What is the best way to achieve the same thing?                   :D